# LINQ Rest Services - Joining across services

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, web-services, rest

Hi Im creating a car hire web service but I need to keep each Task seperate from one another. So I have made a service for Customers which is just generic first name, last name, age etc. I have also made a Hire Dates service which has hire from and to dates and number of days the hire is (will be used later to calculate cost).

My Problem is trying to **link** `IHireDates` to `ICustomers` (and eventualy cars) below is an example of the setup im just using console apps to host these different services to practice.

[image]

Below is my ICustomers and IHireDate Services I am attempting to linq the IHireDate to the Customer but im not sure how to do it:

**ICustomer (Server Side)**

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary3
{
    #region Customer DataContract
    [DataContract(Name = "Customers")]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    [Serializable]
    public class Customers : ICustomers
    {

            [DataMember(Name = "CustomerID")]
            public string CustomerID { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "FirstName")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "LastName")]
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "Age")]
            public string Age { get; set; }
```

**IHireDates (Server Side):**

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary3
{
    #region HireDate DataContract
    [DataContract(Name = "HireDate")]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    [Serializable]
    public class HireDate : IHireDate
    {
    [DataMember(Name = "HireFromDate")]
    public string HireFromDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "HireToDate")]
    public string HireToDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "NumberOfDaysToHire")]
    public string NumberOfDaysToHire { get; set; }

    #endregion

        #region Lists
        List<HireDate> HireDates = new List<HireDate>();
        #endregion

        public void ICustomers.AddCustomerHireDates(string hirefromdate, string hiretodate, string customerID, string firstname, string lastname)
        {
            // not sure this will work
            var result = ICustomers.Where(n => String.Equals(n.CustomerID, customerID)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (result != null)
            {
                result.HireDates.Add(new ICustomers() { CustomerID = customerID, FirstName = firstname, LastName = lastname });
            }
        }
```

For instance Im not sure if this is correct `ICustomers.AddCustomerHireDates` and `ICustomers.Where` says customers has no definition for where. Really not sure how to do this cross LINQ services if someone could help I would be very grateful.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WcfServiceLibrary3
{
    #region Customer DataContract
    [DataContract(Name = "Customers")]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    [Serializable]
    public class Customers : ICustomers
    {

            [DataMember(Name = "CustomerID")]
            public string CustomerID { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "FirstName")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "LastName")]
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "Age")]
            public string Age { get; set; }

    #endregion

            #region Lists
            List<Customers> customermembers = new List<Customers>();
            int eCount = 0;
            #endregion

            public void AddCustomer(Customers customer)
            {
                customer.CustomerID = (++eCount).ToString();
                customermembers.Add(customer);
                //BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
                //Stream w = new FileStream("c:\\list.dat", FileMode.Append);
                //f.Serialize(w, staff);
                //w.Close();
            }
            public void RemoveCustomer(string customerID)
            {
                customermembers.RemoveAll(s => s.CustomerID == customerID);
            }
            public List<Customers> GetCustomerCollection()
            {
                return customermembers;
            }
            public void UpdateCustomer(string customerID, Customers customer)
            {
                var findCustomerMember = customermembers.Where(s => s.CustomerID == customerID).FirstOrDefault();

                if (findCustomerMember != null)
                {
                    findCustomerMember.CustomerID = customer.CustomerID;
                    findCustomerMember.FirstName = customer.FirstName;
                    findCustomerMember.LastName = customer.LastName;
                    //findStaffMember.TimeAdded = staff.TimeAdded;
                    //BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
                    //Stream w = new FileStream("c:\\updatelist.dat", FileMode.Append);
                    //f.Serialize(w, staff);
                    //w.Close();
                }

            }
            public List<Customers> GetCustomer(string anything)
            {


                List<Customers> customers = customermembers.Where(n =>
                                               string.Equals(n.CustomerID, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                               || string.Equals(n.FirstName, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                               || string.Equals(n.LastName, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                               || string.Equals(n.Age, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                                           ).ToList();
                return customers;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know it would make more sense doing all of this within just the "car" service or all of it under one roof but im forced to seperate the services.

Comment: How you are able to create instance of interface new ICustomers(), I think thats wrong.

Comment: :S yeah totaly lost how to do this damm "SOA" and its "split your services up into a million peaces" arghh keyboard rage commencing! Not only am I lost with that im lost with the LINQ on how its done.

Comment: It wont Work like that Where extension method works only with IEnumerable<T> .

Comment: SO how could I go about it, I mean this was fine when I was doing it all under the one IService, but when you have seperate services....

Comment: Do you have List/Collection of Customers. If yes where it is?

Comment: Inside ICustomers but its not reachable from IHireDate see update on question for whats inside ICustomers

Comment: For that first you will have to fetch collection of Customers first and then can apply operations on it .

Comment: can you please show entire code of Customers class.

Comment: @ethicallogics ok updated with full code. IHire is just whats there.

Comment: Ok I got it . What are you expecting the output of this method.

Comment: I mean What your method AddCustomerHireDates do? or what are you expecting this method to do?

Comment: The method will just contain the start date and end date of the car hire and the total days of the hire I need some way tho to reference this to a particular customer i.e customer B has hired Car B from this date to this date. p.s i will be adding a ICar service which holds the car details colour registration number etc but at the moment the qouting system (client side) goes like this: Add new customer, choose hire dates, choose car, choose insurance type and finaly get Qoute

Comment: Later tho the system should be able to: choose a customer and display car hired and on what dates.

Answer (score 0):

unless you want to write you own LINQ provider, you'll have to resort to using LINQ to Objects.  This means you have to load results from both services and hen perform a join.

I really don't think this is a good idea and I think going down that route will be fraught with issues.

The alternative is writing you own rdbms of sorts (and probably a LINQ provider to wrap it). Yet another route I don't recommend.

I suppose you could have a *third* service to serve up the data for the other two services, so you can have all the data in one place in order to be able to truly join.

Comment: I thought about the third service, just have the data contracts in the IServices then do all the fidly LINQ work in one master class. But that wouldnt explain how you would push each service out on different ports. SOA explains that tasks, entitys and utilitys are suppose to stand independant of one another. And im tasked with making sure that each are seperate and result in independant modules going out on different ports.

Comment: If they're independent then you wouldn't join on the data.  If you need to join, then they're not independent and SOA suggests they should be in the same service.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public Customer GetCustomerByHireDates(string hirefromdate, string hiretodate)
    {
        var customerID = HireDates.Where(h => h.HireFromDate == hirefromdate && h.HireToDate == hiretodate).Select(sl=>sl.CustomerID).FirstOrDefault();
        Customers customer = null;
        var customers = new Customers().GetCustomerCollection();
        if (customers != null)
        {
            customer = customers.Where(c=>c.CustomerID==customerID).FirstOrDefault();

        }
        return customer;  
    }
```

I expect HireDates List in HireDate class contains the HireDates and also HireDate class has properties HireFromDate and HireToDate and CustomerID

Comment: Ah wait I made a mistake with the datacontract in hiredate (was a copy and paste) the datamembers had the wrong string names. But also just of note `public Customer` refrences to nothing.

Comment: Also note `(c => c.CustomerID == customerID)` no string was mentioned for customerID and `.Select(sl => sl.CustomerID)` HireDate doesnt contain the definition.